# How to set up Wifi on Beaglebone black when it does not have a wifi example in etc/network/interfaces

Tags: debian, wifi, beagleboneblack

How do I set up wifi when there is no Wifi example in interfaces? All I have is

```
connman: WiFi
#
#connmanctl
#connmanctl> tether wifi off
connmanctl> enable wifi
connmanctl> scan wifi
connmanctl> services
connmanctl> agent on
connmanctl> connect wifi_*_managed_psk
#connmanctl> quit
```

Also when I try conmanctl> enable wifi  I get wifi: not a shell builtin

Answer (score 0):

Type this, in this order, to get your connmanctl command to work properly for WiFi.

wifi enable

wifi scan

services

agent on

connect wifi___managed_psk

then...

It should ask you for your password. Enter the password of your router. If this does not work, just reply. I learned this from a man in the #beagle, IRC channel on Freenode. Oh and the services command shows you an elongated amount of numbers and letters, mostly, where you would then use the connect command to type in what you saw when you typed in the services command. Be sure to type agent on command before the connect command.

Seth

Comment: root@beaglebone:/home/debian# sudo conmant|
> enable wifi
bash: enable: wifi: not a shell builtin
sudo: conmant: command not found     (this is what i get when i try that)

Comment: Hello...have you tried a newer kernel version or an updated image, i.e. one that the bbb.io people have listed on their site or at http://elinux.org/Beagleboard:BeagleBoneBlack_Debian#Privileged_echo?

Comment: I updated my image and updated via sudo apt-get update on my BBB, I followed my instructions I received from #beagle, and then all of the WiFi started to work. Oh and I upgraded via sudo apt-get upgrade to get up to speed on security patches and such.

Comment: Oh and Mr. John...you will need a "Linux Approved" WiFi adapter for your WiFi experience on your BBB, i.e. since it does not come with WiFi. There are other items that you can use like BBBW and the BBGW for WiFi services if those recommendations do not work. Let me know and I will look through my book on what available WiFi dongles work.

Comment: Hello Seth, When I try connect wifi___managed_psk I get this error: Error /net/connman/service/wifi_daly_managed_psk: Method "Connect" with signature "" on interface "net.connman.Service" doesn't exist

Comment: What prints on your command  line when you apply "cat /etc/dogtag" and "uname -a"

Answer (score 0):

John,

I just added another board to my WiFi configuration. This time, I needed to apply different changes but I do not know every, single reason.

First,

I had to do this:

**connmanctl: services**

Then, it told me my WiFi available networks.

Then, while still under the connmanctl command:

**connmanctl: agent on**

**connmanctl: connect "available network"**

**connmanctl: passcode "router password"**

Seth

P.S. Let me know what type of WiFi dongle you are using and I can help you from that portion of the task.

Comment: Every conmanct| command i use i just get bash: conmant: command not found. Also i'm using ourlink and it shows up when i run iwconfig

Comment: Hey John...what type of WiFi dongle are you using, e.g. edimax or another?

Comment: elinux . org /Beagleboard:BeagleBoneBlack#WIFI_Adapters is a good site to look for available WiFi adapters for your BBB. Oh and Mr. John, that adafruit product has info. below on how to set up the WiFi dongle. I just do not think that version is available for the BBB and Debian. Let me know what you think.

Answer (score 0):

Mr. Daly...try this.

**lsusb**

This should detect your USB client attached to the BBB.

Let me know if this works for you. Oh and then **update** your BBB, use your cmd line for a **apt-cache search 'your USB WiFi dongle'** that you found with the **lsusb** cmd.

If this works, we need to then update your firmware for your USB Wifi Dongle.

ifconfig -a will, if all goes well, show the adapter (WiFi Dongle) as wlan0 or another variant like wlanX or something.

Sir...let me know how far you get with these descriptions and I will return service.

Seth

Comment: It gets more complicated but I am sure I can walk you through it. I will probably learn something along the line, too.

Answer (score 0):

Plese follow this

```
oot@beaglebone:~# ifconfig wlan0
wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr ec:11:27:bf:fa:51
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST DYNAMIC  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:833 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:142 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:114829 (112.1 KiB)  TX bytes:26578 (25.9 KiB)





root@beaglebone:~# connmanctl
connmanctl> enable wifi
Enabled wifi
connmanctl> tether wifi disable
Disabled tethering for wifi



connmanctl> scan wifi
Scan completed for wifi
connmanctl> services
        wheelies2.4          wifi_ec1127bffa51_776865656c696573322e34_managed_psk
        ATT5363              wifi_ec1127bffa51_41545435333633_managed_psk
        2WIRE407             wifi_ec1127bffa51_3257495245343037_managed_psk
        ATT8fHHhfi           wifi_ec1127bffa51_41545438664848686669_managed_psk
connmanctl>



connmanctl> agent on
Agent registered
connmanctl>
connmanctl> connect wifi_ec1127bffa51_776865656c696573322e34_managed_psk
Agent RequestInput wifi_ec1127bffa51_776865656c696573322e34_managed_psk
  Passphrase = [ Type=psk, Requirement=mandatory, Alternates=[ WPS ] ]
  WPS = [ Type=wpspin, Requirement=alternate ]
Passphrase? your_password
connmanctl>
Connected wifi_ec1127bffa51_776865656c696573322e34_managed_psk
connmanctl>
```